# HTML5 Drag and drop parent from child element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of elements and in each element there is a handle control element. I can easily drag and drop the elements to reorder. However I'm unsure to limit the drag start to the handle element.

eg:

```
<ul>
    <li draggable="true" ondragstart="..." ondrop="..." ondragover="..."><div class="reorder"></div>Item 1</li>
    <li draggable="true" ondragstart="..." ondrop="..." ondragover="..."><div class="reorder"></div>Item 2</li>
    <li draggable="true" ondragstart="..." ondrop="..." ondragover="..."><div class="reorder"></div>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

In the above code, I can click and drag on the handle element or the text "Item #" to reorder them.

I thought in the ondragstart function I could check if the class of the `event.target` is handle and if not do `event.preventDefault()` but it seems the target is always the `li` whether the drag starts from the `div` or `li`.

So is there a way to check if the mouse was over a child element on the ondragstart event

Comment: I'm having the same issue, where you able to figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

Im based on the comments of Mouser. See this example:

```
var object = document.querySelector('li');

var dragger = document.querySelector('li .reorder');

dragger.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  object.setAttribute('draggable','true');
});

dragger.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
  object.removeAttribute('draggable');
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOWJYF

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve this problem the other way around.
Set the ondragstart on the *div*, then when the users clicks on the div, set draggable to *true* for the *li*. When dropped set draggable back to *false*. This way you dragging only happens when the users uses the *reorder* *div*.
You can simply register the object into the global scope

```
 function dragStart(event) {
   globalDraggedElement = this.parentElement;
   this.parentElement.draggable = true;
 }

function dragOver(event) {

  if (globalDraggedElement != this) {
    //If the element is not the dragged element, show mouse drop cursor.
    //Else show forbidden to drop cursor, by default.
     event.preventDefault();
  }

}

function dragDrop(event) {
  if (globalDraggedElement != this) {
    //perform action!

  }
  globalDraggedElement.draggable = false;
  //Delete the element from the global scope.
  delete globalDraggedElement;
}

function dragEnd(event) {
        this.draggable = false;

}

var liElement = document.querySelectorAll("li[draggable='true']");
for (var i = 0; i < liElement.length; ++i) {
  liElement[i].children[0].addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart, false);
  liElement[i].addEventListener('dragenter', dragOver, false);
  liElement[i].addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
  liElement[i].addEventListener('drop', dragDrop, false);
  liElement[i].addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd, false);
}
```

Please use the addEventListeners to add events. I used document.querySelectorAll to select all li elements with the draggable property set to true. [helpful article at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)
[dragdrop](/questions/tagged/dragdrop)